# Finding last value before end of line

Tags: c++, regex, for-loop, iterator

I'm working on a program which parses tags and alters the colour of the text in the console via escape codes. The input is read line by line from cin, and when a tag in <> is read it is checked against a map I made to determine a valid escape code.

My out put is delivered to standard out using the following output:

```
cout << m.prefix() << getFromMap(tagMap, stack.back());
```

My problem is unless i have an even number of codes on the line I can't print all of the input due to the last of it being in the smatch m.suffix()

the loop I am using to parse a line for regex is

```
for (auto it = uline.cbegin(), end = uline.cend(); regex_search(it, end, m, tag); it = m.suffix().first)
```

Now I need to design an if statement that fires when the next it == uline.cend()
so that I can

```
cout<<m.suffix();
```

full loop dump for relevance:

```
while (getline(cin, uline)) {
    //Check line for tags
    for (auto it = uline.cbegin(), end = uline.cend(); regex_search(it, end, m, tag); it = m.suffix().first) {

        ctag = m.str(1);

        //if closing tag
        if (ctag[0] == '/') {
            //Error for closing <text> early
            if (ctag == "/text" && stack.size() > 1) {
                cerr << getFromMap(tagMap, "text") << "ERROR on line " << count << " unclosed tags before</text>" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
            //check current tag against back if yes alter stack
            if (ctag.substr(1) == stack.back() && stack.size() > 0) {
                stack.pop_back();
            }
            //if not tags are improperly nested throw error
            else {
                cerr << getFromMap(tagMap, "text") << "ERROR on line " << count << " improperly nested tags" << endl;
            }
        }
        //if opening tag.
        else {
            //Failure to find tag in map
            if (!(findInMap(tagMap, m[1]))) {
                cerr << getFromMap(tagMap, "text") << "ERROR on line " << count << " tag not found in map" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
            //Check for bad input 
            if (first) {
                //Check for <text> being first tag
                if (m[1] != "text") {
                    cerr << getFromMap(tagMap, "text") << "ERROR on line " << count << " first tag not <text>" << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
                //Check for input before <text> 
                if (!m.prefix().str().empty() && !checkEmpty(m.prefix().str()))
                {
                    cerr << getFromMap(tagMap, "text") << "ERROR on line " << count << " text precedes <text> tag" << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            //add to stack if all tests passed
            stack.push_back(m[1]);
            first = false;
        }
        //should output here
        cout << m.prefix() << getFromMap(tagMap, stack.back());
    }

    cout << endl;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to treat the entire input as a single document, because opening and closing tags might be on separate lines.  An easy way to do this is to use iterators on the input stream rather than on each line:

```
for (auto it = istream_iterator<char>(cin), end = istream_iterator<char>();
    regex_search(it, end, m, tag); it = m.suffix().first) {
    // ...
```